# Knockout - Mapping an array

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

First of all, I have a JSFiddle representing exactly the results that I need to accomplished and it works: http://jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/wG9SZ/

However, I need it to integrate this code structure into a bigger project that has already multiple bindings, therefore I can't only bind to an array as in the previous JSFiddle.

So, I need my JSON Object to be mapped but this object has to be inside a function or a viewModel.

Normally, my html should stay the same or close to.

Here's my js code of what I'm attempting to do:

```
function appViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.formData = ko.observableArray();
    self.formData.push({"data": 
        [
            {
            "groupName" : "Properties",
            "content" : 
            [
                {
                    "title" : "Calculation Method",
                    "formType" : "select",
                    "selected" : "2",
                    "value" : 
                    [
                        {
                            "title" : "Voltage Drop - Unbalanced",
                            "value" : "1"
                        },
                        {
                            "title" : "Voltage Drop - Balanced",
                            "value" : "2"
                        }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "title" : "Tolerance (% V)",
                    "formType" : "textBox",
                    "value" : 0.01
                },

                {
                    "title" : "Calculation Options",
                    "formType" : "checkbox",
                    "value" : 
                    [ 
                        {
                            "title" : "Flat Start (at Nominal Conditions",
                            "checked" : false
                        } ,
                        {
                            "title" : "Assume Line Transposition",
                            "checked" : true
                        }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "title" : "Adjust Conductor Resistance at",
                    "formType" : "textBox",
                    "disabled" : true,
                    "value" : 77,
                    "appendLabel" : true,
                    "appendLabelText" : "°F"    
                }
            ]
            },
            {
            "groupName" : "Properties",
            "content" : 
            [
                {
                    "title" : "Calculation Method",
                    "formType" : "select",
                    "value" : 
                    [
                        {
                            "title" : "Voltage Drop - Unbalanced",
                            "selected" : false

                        },
                        {
                            "title" : "Voltage Drop - Balanced",
                            "selected" : true
                        }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "title" : "Tolerance (% V)",
                    "formType" : "textBox",
                    "value" : 0.01
                },

                {
                    "title" : "Calculation Options",
                    "formType" : "checkbox",
                    "value" : 
                    [ 
                        {
                            "title" : "Flat Start (at Nominal Conditions",
                            "checked" : false
                        } ,
                        {
                            "title" : "Assume Line Transposition",
                            "checked" : true
                        }
                    ]
                },

                {
                    "title" : "Adjust Conductor Resistance at",
                    "formType" : "textBox",
                    "disabled" : true,
                    "value" : 77,
                    "appendLabel" : true,
                    "appendLabelText" : "°F"    
                }
            ]
            }
        ]
    });  
}

var viewModel = new appViewModel()

ko.mapping.fromJS(viewModel.formData)
ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
```

This code is also available here: http://jsfiddle.net/etiennenoel/wG9SZ/23/

Now, it doesn't work and I don't know why. I really need my `formData` to be inside a function. The problem is that the documentation does not talk about doing something like that...

**Is there a way to do that ?**

**If not, is there a way for knockout to be binded to a function and a variable at the same time ?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You only frogot one binding level :

```
<div data-bind="foreach: formData">
    <div data-bind="foreach: data"> <!-- missing -->
         <h1 data-bind="text: $data.groupName"></h1>
```

[**See fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wG9SZ/26/)